# TensorFlow - how to suppress printing in scientific notation?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

How can I suppress TensorFlow printing in scientific notation?  I'm using TensorFlow 2.6.
Example:

```
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "1"
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003], dtype=tf.float32)

print(x)
```

Example output:

```
tf.Tensor([1.e-04 2.e-04 3.e-04], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
```

Would prefer:

```
tf.Tensor([0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
```

I realize I could add the line `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` and then convert to numpy when printing like this:

```
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "1"
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

x = tf.constant([0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003], dtype=tf.float32)

print(x.numpy())
```

But I would prefer the option to suppress scientific notation directly in TensorFlow if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.print()`, which prints the specified inputs to a desired output stream or logging level.

```
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "1"
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003], dtype=tf.float32)
tf.print(x)
```

Output:

```
[0.0001 0.0002 0.0003]
```